# Creating a size specific Numpy Array, and then filling it with values at a steped rate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a totally lost newbie, whose goal is to write a script that creates a random integer grid, where user input specifies the number of rows, the number of columns, the high and low values, and the step at which the values between the high and low are counted (for instance count from 0 to 10 by twos). Using that input, the grid is then filled with randomly generated integers that fit the criteria. I know I can use "np.arange" to set the range and step value, and then use resize to get the array to the right size, but what I am totally stuck on is getting the rest of the 0 values in the array once it is resized to fit the range and step values. How would I go about doing this? My code so far:

```
num_rows = int(raw_input("How many rows in the raster? "))
num_cols = int(raw_input("How many columns in the raster? "))
low_range = int(raw_input("What is the lowest value in the raster? "))
hi_range = int(raw_input("What is the highest value in the raster? "))
step_range = int(raw_input("What is the value step you would like? "))

user_raster = np.arange(low_range,hi_range,step_range)
user_raster2 = user_raster.resize((num_rows, num_cols), refcheck=False)
```

Running this with 5 rows, 5 columns, a low value of 0, a high of 10, and a step of two results in

```
[[0 2 4 6 8]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]]
```

So how do I go about replacing the 0's with the values 0-10 at a step of 2? I know there are options like "append" and "insert" but those don't give me the option of doing it at a stepped rate.

Or (most likely) there is a better way to approach this in general? One critical flaw I realize is that the high value is higher than the row count, then the top range of values will be cut off and not placed in the grid when randomly generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `user_raster` array is only 5 elements long in your example, when you resize it to 5x5 `np.ndarray.resize` fills the extra space with zeros. You could use `np.resize` (emphasis added for `ndarray.resize` behaviour):

> Definition:  np.resize(a, new_shape)
>
> Docstring: Return a new array
>   with the specified shape.
>
> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array
>   is filled with repeated copies of `a`.  Note that this behavior is
>   different from a.resize(new_shape) which **fills with zeros** instead of
>   repeated copies of `a`.

```
rows = 5
cols = 5
low = 0
hi = 10
step = 2

user_raster = np.arange(low, hi, step)
# array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
user_raster2 = np.resize(user_raster, (rows, cols))
# Output:
array([[0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

A trick you can use for arrays of this type is to use `np.mgrid`:

```
low = 0
hi = 10
step = 2
axis = 1  # horizontal

np.mgrid[low:hi:step, low:hi:step][axis]
# Output:
array([[0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]])
```